# $f(x) = \arctan x | x\in R$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x) = \arctan x | x\in R$. Then

1) $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all positive even integers n.

2)the sequence ${f^{(n)} (0)}$ is unbounded.

Are they correct?

How can derivative of more than three degree be computed?

Comment: Hint: look at the Taylor series for your function

Comment: yea I checked it ..So two are  correct.. Is it not true?@User8128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\arctan(x)
&=\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
&=\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(2k)(2k-1)\cdots(2k-(n-2))x^{2k-(n-1)}\\
\end{align}$$

At $x=0$, the only term that is nonzero is the $k=(n-1)/2$ term, which is only present when $n$ is odd. So for even $n$, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$. And for odd $n$,
 $$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^{(n-1)/2}[2(n-1)/2][2(n-1)/2-1]\cdots[2(n-1)/2-(n-2)]$$
 $$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^{(n-1)/2}(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(1)=(-1)^{(n-1)/2}(n-1)!$$ which is unbounded.